# how to add File Format Icons next to link by using css

Tags: html, css

I have multiple links for Pdf, Doc, and Docx files that I want to show the File Format Icons next to it by using CSS only

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/resume.pdf"> Persone Name </a>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/resume.doc"> Persone Name </a>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/resume.docx"> Persone Name </a>
```

I tried but it applies pdf icon on all

```
a::after{
    content: " " url("pdf-icon.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a[href$=".pdf"]{
    content: " " url("pdf-icon.png");
}
```

It selects the `a` elements whose `href` attribute's content ends with `.pdf`

See also: [Substring matching attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)